# Upper to lowercase function C

Tags: c, function

I want to write a program in C that will change the letters of a text from uppercase to lowercase using a function, but it will leave the first letters of each sentence uppercase.
For exaple LEAF. IS? GREEN! I need to convert it to Leaf.Is? Green!

```
#include <stdio.h>

char upper_to_low(char s[]) {   
    int c = 0;
    while (s[c] != '\0') {
        if ((s[c] >= 'A' && s[c] <= 'Z') && c > 0) {
            s[c] = s[c] + 32;
        }
        c++;
    }
}

int main() {
    char text[100];

    printf("Text\n");
    gets(text);
    upper_to_lower(text);
    printf("This is the text\n %s", text);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what output does the above give?

Comment: If I write THE LEAF IS GREEN. The output is The leaf is green. So it works but just for the first sentence because it skip the first character.

Answer (score 3):

That's because of your `&& c>0` condition, which skips the first letter, but does not "reset" to allow you skip any letters after it.

You can add a flag that indicates if the next character should be converted, like this:

```
int c = 0;
int shouldConvert = 0;
while (s[c] != '\0') {
    if (s[c] >= 'A' && s[c] <= 'Z') {
        if (shouldConvert) {
            s[c] += 'a'-'A';
        } else {
            shouldConvert = 1;
        }
    } else {
        shouldConvert = 0;
    }
    c++;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/vAYrLp)

**Note:** Consider using `s[c] += 'a'-'A'` as a more readable alternative of `s[c] = s[c] +32`

Comment: @Nica Isn't that what you are complaining about, or did I misinterpret "but it will leave the first letters of each sentence uppercase" part? I though that you meant that leaving the first letter an uppercase was not desirable.

Comment: This new requirement is invalidating the whole code. Now you need to parse the sentence for punctuation.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Parsing for non-uppercase should work too (that's what my code does).

Comment: The reply was to the removed @Nica s comment, requiring to preserve uppercase letters in the beginning of *each* sentence. Your answer is valid for the question as it was originally.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ah, I see. He should be able to figure out what to do, though - basically, all he needs to add is conditions around assignments of `shouldConvert` to decide what to do going into the next character.